# Python-list is too large and can't be deleted

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have an iterator/generator which yields 'events'. An event consists of a name, a timestamp and a value. I want to store them in NumPy arrays.
This is done in `_LoadTriples()`:

```
def _LoadTriples(abortEvt, count=[1]):
    it = _YieldTriples()
    while True:
        if abortEvt.is_set():
            it.close()
            break
        t0 = time.time()
        self.allEvents.append(np.fromiter(it,
                                      dtype=[('sigNameIdx', 'i'),
                                             ('time', 'f'),
                                             ('value', 'f8')],
                                      count=count[-1]))
        dur = time.time() - t0
        if dur < 0.2:
            count.append(count[-1]*2)
        elif dur > 0.4 and count[-1] != 1:
            count.append(count[-1]/2)
        else:
            count.append(count[-1])
```

`_YieldTriples` is the generator, `abortEvt` is the Event that tells me when the user abortes the iteration. `self.allEvents` is an empty list. Here I want to append NumPy arrays with the Triples `(name, timestamp, value).` It is a list of arrays because I want to have the possibility to break the iteration and I can't break `numpy.fromiter`. So every about 0.3 seconds I can stop the iteration.

That all works fine. *But*, in one example it happens that Python quickly uses up 300MB memory for the list! When I stop the iteration my list only needs max 10 MB, depending on when I stopped it, but after some few calls to `self.allEvents.append(np.fromiter(...))` 300MB are used and I have absolutely no idea why.

Furthermore this memory isn't freed until I stop the whole program, even if I delete `self.allEvents` directly after the call of that function. There must be some references which prevent me from releasing it. Is there any way to see which objects have references to the list?

One thing more to be mentioned: The function is called as a new `threading.Thread`, but the mainthread waits for it...

Edit: I didn't mention, no more memory is allocated as the list grows, once the 300MB are in use. It seems like the list reserves this memory after some appends.

Comment: I'm not positive what the problem is, but you're using a mutable default argument.  Any changes you make to `count` here will persist eternally in your program (unless you resort to some trickery to change that behavior).

Comment: define "used" python typically does not give back memory but rather recycles it once aquired.

Comment: @mgilson: The problem is that too much memory is allocated and I can't free it. After some callings of this function out of my program I get MemoryError... And yes it is mutable, that wasn't my intent, but doesn't matter either, see below.

Comment: @seberg: it should give the memory back when I delete the list... but it doesn't, the memory is used until the program ends

Comment: And you know that because...? After deleting run it again, and see if the memory increases further.

Comment: That is what I did, after about 5 calls of _LoadTriples I got Memory Error. The used memory always increases by 300MB ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should try:

```
def _LoadTriples(abortEvt, count=None):
    if count is None:
        count = [1]
    ...
```

Mutable default arguments can lead to the problems very fast.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, that isn't very clever. In fact I don't have any default argument there in my program, I just put it there that you can see that `count` is a list that starts/ends with 1... But this has nothing to do with my memory problem